# Latex bibliography with long list of author names

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, errors

So the issue I have is that, when I use

```
@article{SK2,   
author = {N. Bansal, H. Jiang, R. Meka},   
year = {1997},   
title = {Smoothed Analysis of the Koml\'os Conjecture},   
journal = {Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences of the United States of America},   
volume = {94},   
pages = {14614 - 14619}   
}
```

It shows up and everything is fine. The problem is that I need
the authors to include a few more.

Hence when I change the code to

```
@article{SK2,   
author = {N. Bansal, H. Jiang, R. Meka, S. Singla, M. Sinha.},   
year = {1997},   
title = {Smoothed Analysis of the Koml\'os Conjecture},   
journal = {Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences of the United States of America},   
volume = {94},   
pages = {14614 - 14619}   
}
```

BibTeX stops working and issues the error message

> Too many commas in name 1 of "N. Bansal, H. Jiang, R. Meka, S. Singla, M. Sinha." for entry SK2.

I don't understand why a few more characters make a difference.

How do I fix this?

Comment: The is not the correct syntax for authors, instead of commas use the _word_ ` and ` between each and remove the `.` at the end. ` and ` is a part of the bibtex data format, and then up to the style used (either in bibtex or biblatex) to format it.

Comment: Thus the correct is `author = {N. Bansal and H. Jiang and R. Meka and S. Singla and M. Sinha}, `

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Off-topic: You should replace `Koml\'os` with `{Koml\'os}` in order to prevent BibTeX from converting the word to all-lowercase.

Comment: You wrote that "everything is fine" if `author = {N. Bansal, H. Jiang, R. Meka}`. I strongly doubt that. I suspect that BibTeX is rendering the `author` component of the entry at hand as "R. Meka N. Bansal, H. Jiang", or something similar.  This happens because, according to BibTeX's syntax rules for parsing author names, `N. Bansal, H. Jiang, R. Meka` is interpreted as a *single author* whose surname is `N. Bansal` (*not* `Bansal`), whose first or given names are "R." and "Meka", and whose "junior" name component could be "H. Jiang" [!]. Moral of the story? Learn how to use the keyword `and`.